# Transform in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

this code does not plot correctly. Can anyone help me out?

```
temps = [600, 800, 1000, 1200]
diffusivities = [1.051923179496762e-06, 5.731093899237634e-06, 1.7662071594257596e-05, 4.969165609541332e-05]
arr = c * np.exp(-Ea / (const.k / const.e * np.array(temps)))
t_1 = 1000 / np.array(temps)
plt.plot(t_1, diffusivities, "ko", t_1, arr, "k--", markersize=10, **kwargs)
plt.text(15, 6, f"E$_a$ = {(Ea * 1000):.0f} meV", fontsize=30, transform=plt.axes().transAxes)
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_yscale("log")
plt.tight_layout()
```

Here is its result:
[image: wrong]

I would like to have a result like the following:
[image: correct]

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. Removed the `**kwargs` in `plt.plot()`, maybe you can check what you passed there.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
from collections import namedtuple
Ea = .391
c = 10
Const = namedtuple("Const", ["k", "e"])
const = Const(k=.35, e=10000)
temps = [600, 800, 1000, 1200]
diffusivities = [1.051923179496762e-06, 5.731093899237634e-06, 1.7662071594257596e-05, 4.969165609541332e-05]
arr = c * np.exp(-Ea / (const.k / const.e * np.array(temps)))
t_1 = 1000 / np.array(temps)
plt.plot(t_1, diffusivities, "ko", t_1, arr, "k--", markersize=10)
plt.text(0.5, .7, f"E$_a$ = {(Ea * 1000):.0f} meV", fontsize=20, transform=plt.axes().transAxes)
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_yscale("log")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I tried several times, but it does not work like this

Comment: Maybe if you update your question with complete code , I can help. The code in your question is not complete. The values for `Ea` and `const` are missing.